# Google glass : How to remove a livecard after publishing it?

Tags: google-glass

I'm actually working on an application for Google Glass.
Does anybody know how to remove a livecard once it had been published ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [LiveCard.unpublish()](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/LiveCard#unpublish())

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have already used it and it doesn't work as I want. In fact, I have a service which publish many liveCard at different moments. When I click on one Livecard it is removed and for the other ones it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you need to provide some sample code and further details about what you're doing. Might also want to look at logcat to see if it gives any errors and, if so, post what it says.

Comment: It sounds like you'd need to keep a reference to each of the live cards you create and call `.unpublish` on each of them.